# Element Not Interactable Exception Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, exception

````
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException```


    website = 'https://shipsupply.org/issa-register/'
    
    path = 'C:\\Users\\Wishes Lawrence\\Documents\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe'
    chrome_options=Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(website)
    time.sleep(2)
````

**Step 1: Click on each flag
and get all links**

```
titles_s=[]
Location_s=[]
Name_s=[]
Phones_s=[]
Email_s=[]
Phones_2=[]
Email_2=[]`

countries=WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath', '//ul[@class="first-level"]/li')))

print(len(countries))

for country in countries:
    print(country)
    try:
        countries=WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath', '//ul[@class="first-level"]/li')))
        print(country.click())
    except StaleElementReferenceException as Exception: 
        WebDriverWait(driver, 35).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath', '//ul[@class="first-level"]/li//a')))                                                        
       
    org_links = driver.find_elements('xpath', '//h1[@class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"]//a')
    print("Org_links:",len(org_links))
```

**Click on each link.**
**When org.click() is clicked I get Element Not Interactable error**

```
      for org in org_links:
          try:
              org_links=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath', '//h1[@class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"]//a')))
              print(org_links)
              time.sleep(2)
              org.click()
              
          except StaleElementReferenceException as Exception: 
              WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath', '//h1[@class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"]//a')))      
          driver.back()
          time.sleep(2)
  #     return_to_ql= WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath','//span/span[@class="elementor-button-text"]/text()'))).click()
      driver.back()
```

Comment: to enable others to reason about your long code, I would suggest editing your question to improve the formatting, narrow down only to the code related to the exception you are facing, and also to share the relevant narrowed-down HTML code related to the elements you are interacting and raising the exception.

Comment: Thanks.Have made the change ,please help me to resolve the isse

Comment: Have you tried waiting until the org link you're targeting becomes interactable? When you collect the links, you're only waiting until they exist, not until they become active and visible. A quick search found more information here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/interactions/

Comment: Thanks Kate will try and keep you posted

Comment: org_links=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(('xpath', '//h1[@class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"]//a')))
Post which it gave me atime out exception
**TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 51
     49 for org in org_links:
     50     try:
---> 51         org_links=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(('xpath', '//h1[@class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"]//a')))
     52         print(org_links)
     53         time.sleep(2)**